# Загрузка фотографий на стену пользователя vk

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь сделать пост записи на стену vk (текстовое сообщение и фото). Для этого нужно загрузить фотографию на стену пользователя. Делаю по документации:

1. С помощью метода photos.getWallUploadServer приложение узнает http-адрес для загрузки фотографии на стену текущего пользователя, другого пользователя или группы в зависимости от переданных параметров user_id или group_id.

   ```
   var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?gid=' + Ti.App.Properties.getString('vk_user_id') + '&access_token=' + Ti.App.Properties.getString('vk_access_token');
   ```

   После чего делаю запрос

   ```
   client.open('GET', url);
   client.send();
   ```

   Приходит http-адрес для загрузки фотографии на стену текущего пользователя.
2. Далее хочу загрузить фотографию. Приложение формирует POST-запрос на полученный адрес. Запрос должен включать поле photo, содержащее файл с изображением (JPG, PNG, BMP или GIF)

   ```
   var client_2 = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
       onload: function() {
       alert(this.responseText);
       },
       onerror: function(e) {
           modalWindows.createAlert(e.error);
       },
       timeout: 5000
   });
   client_2.open('POST', resUrl); //resUrl http-адрес
   client_2.setRequestHeader('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
   client_2.send({photo: $.walkPhoto.getImage()});
   ```

В итоге приходит ответ

> {"server": "622930", "photo": "[]", "hash": "12345abcde"}

Не знаю почему приходит photo как пустой массив.

Comment: Может быть ответ на ваш вопрос [тут](https://toster.ru/q/191399) ?